# Stop Watch application

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I've done the difficult [dailyprogrammer challenge #2](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/pjsdx/difficult_challenge_2/):

> Your mission is to create a stopwatch program. this program should have start, stop, and lap options, and it should write out to a file to be viewed later.

I wanted to see from you guys if what I did was correct. I'm looking for shortcuts or better coding practices I could have missed. This is a Windows Form Application.

```
namespace _Hard0002_StopWatch {
public partial class StopWatchForm : Form {
    StateEnum state;
    Stopwatch stopWatch;
    TimeSpan timeSpan;
    string elapsedTime;
    List<string> times = new List<string>();

    public StopWatchForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        state = StateEnum.Stoped;
    }

    private void StartAndLapButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (state == StateEnum.Stoped) {
            stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            state = StateEnum.Started;
            ChangeButtonText(StartAndLapButton, "Lap");
            ChangeFormTittle("Started");
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        } else if (state == StateEnum.Started) {
            times.Add(elapsedTime);
        }
    }

    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (state == StateEnum.Started) {
            ChangeButtonText(StartAndLapButton, "Start");
            ChangeFormTittle("Stop Watch");
            stopWatch.Stop();
            times.Add(elapsedTime);
            state = StateEnum.Stoped;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void FileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (times.Count > -1) {
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                string path = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path + ".txt", times);
                times.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    void ChangeButtonText(Button button, string text) {
        button.Text = text;
    }

    private void ChangeFormTittle(string text) {
        this.Text = text;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        timeSpan = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);
        TimeKeeperText.Text = elapsedTime;
    }

    ///Your mission is to create a stopwatch program.
    ///this program should have start, stop, and lap options, 
    ///and it should write out to a file to be viewed later.
    ///

    ///Nouns:
    ///Start
    ///lap
    ///stop
    ///file (txt)
    ///
    ///Verbs:
    ///Keeps time
    ///Writes file
    ///
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a lot to review here, so I'll just cover this handler:

> ```
> private void FileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
>     saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
>     saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
>     saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
>     saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
>
>     if (times.Count > -1) {
>         if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
>             string path = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
>             System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path + ".txt", times);
>             times.Clear();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

It's very easy to cram all of a functionality's logic inside an event handler in WinForms; it's a little bit harder to handle a `Click` event and not have the *Single Responsibility Principle* take a beating. This handler:

- Configures and displays a `SaveFileDialog`.
- Writes to the specified file.
- Clears the `times` list.

These are 3 distinct operations, and yet they all happen in the `FileButton`'s `Click` handler.

One of my favorite refactorings, is the *Extract Method* functionality - in Visual Studio, there's a convenient keyboard shortcut for it: just select the code you want to extract, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>.

I would select the first part, extract it into its own function, and get this:

```
private string PromptSaveAsFileName()
{
    var dialog = new SaveFileDialog
        {
            Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*",
            FilterIndex = 2,
            RestoreDirectory = true
        };

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return dialog.FileName;
    }

    return null;
}
```

This would leave the handler, with a few little more changes, like this:

```
private void FileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    if (times.Count == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    var fileName = PromptSaveAsFileName();
    if (fileName == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileName + ".txt", times);
    times.Clear();
}
```

It's still more than I'd like to see, but it's already much better. A few question marks before going any further:

- Under what circumstances would `times.Count` be `-1`?

  > Never. The Count property of an empty list will return 0.
- Since we have a function whose role is to return our `SaveAsFileName`, who's responsibility is it to ensure the file has a `.txt` extension?

  > The function should return the full file name, ready to be used, including its extension.

So. I'd do whatever I have to do, to make the handler look like this:

```
private void FileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!times.Any())
    {
        return;
    }

    var fileName = PromptSaveAsFileName();
    if (fileName == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    WriteResultsToFile(fileName);
    times.Clear();
}
```

Notice a couple more points:

- `{` scope opening brace is placed on the next line. This is C# convention; opening the scope on the same line is Java convention. I like that your brace style is consistent though, so that's just a minor point.
- Return early, and don't work for nothing: the above code will not set up a `new SaveFileDialog` *and then* return if there's nothing to save.
- Avoid extraneous nesting: it's often possible to reduce nesting by simply reversing a condition.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I need to just give up my Java roots and stick with language conventions when they are there. I'd like to post the new code but I feel it would bloat my post even further. Is there a convention `codereview` has to do that?

Comment: Sure! See [this meta post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/23788) for all the details about iterative reviews (please don't edit your question) :)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> namespace _Hard0002_StopWatch {
> ```

It's nitpicky, but I've never seen a namespace begin with an underscore. It just looks weird to me.

While I'm being nit picky, C# tends to have braces on new lines instead of the Egyptian style that you use. ***But***, you were consistent and that's what really matters.

You have a typo here.

> ```
> private void ChangeFormTittle(string text) {
>    this.Text = text;
> }
> ```

But it doesn't matter much, because this method is kind of a useless abstraction. I would just directly set `this.Text = "Started"`, etc.

Comment: I see your point on the namespace. I just named my folder [Hard0002]StopWatch so I can keep track of the challenges. Is there a way better way to name my folders to keep them organized and not have the weird underscore?

Comment: Well, I created a `Challenges` namespace and then [nested a namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6297279/3198973) for each different site and then each prompt got its own file. Seemed to work all right for me.

Comment: If that style is Egyptian, what is the other style?

Comment: @ADTC "Egytian" is really a variant of the K&R style, while the "C#" style is actually the Allman style. [See the style section on this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Styles).